# Windows phone volume key event

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have searched a lot to find the events on physical key i.e. volume key but I didn't get any related information. I have refer this documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207212%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

Is it possible to get access to any of the events raised by volume key in windows phone? Is there any related example, tutorial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current SDK doesn't allow you to subscribe to any event that will let you know if the volume key has been pressed.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is there any example ?

Comment: how to identify that volume key has been pressed ?

Comment: You can't, there is no way to do it.

Comment: Is it Possible by using c++ ?

Comment: I haven't tried C++ on WP but I don't think so. Someone may prove me wrong on that but I imagine if that event was available to C++ code, it should be available to C#.

Comment: No problem, I needed this for a previous app too but it wasn't possible :/